# ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError - Why ruaml.yaml can't represent an np.array?

Tags: python, numpy, yaml, pydantic

I'm new using Pydantic and ruaml.yaml, working actually on a project using these two.

I have an error when I try to load a model config and represent it with mkdocs, It appear that ruaml.yaml is unable to dump on np.array object of my Pydantic schema.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/representer.py", line 337, in represent_undefined
                raise RepresenterError(f'cannot represent an object: {data!s}')
            ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: [0 0 0 0]
```

It happen when I try to represent that :

```
std: Optional[np.ndarray] = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
mean: Optional[np.ndarray] = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Is there a solution or something that I can change ?
Thanks in advance !

TEST :
I try to replace it by :

```
std: Optional[np.ndarray] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
mean: Optional[np.ndarray] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

But need these to be np.array object for the rest of my code..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: consider saving a list instead of an array

Comment: Thanks for ur comment @hpaulj , but in that case I can't ...
I think I've find a way to handle this problem, but need some tests !

Comment: Saving an array to YAML has probably been discussed in other SO.  I suspect it's the same issue as saving to JSON or a database.  Convert to the array to some thing can be saved - a list, or string ('tostring' or 'pickle'), and then on load, convert that back to array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML has several types defined in the [Language Independent types for YAML 1.1](https://yaml.org/type/).
`numpy.array` is not in that list, primarily because it is not language independent, so there is no representation for something non-standard like that.

So you will have to provide a representer yourself, and if you represent it with a tag, you can load back the resulting representation if you provide a constructor for that tag.

It doesn't suffice to make a representer for `numpy.array` though, as neither `std` nor `mean` is of that type, as
you already indicate yourself by the type information you supply. You have to provide a representer for `numpy.ndarray`,
and also for `numpy.float64` (for the elements of `std` and `numpy.int` (for the elements of mean)

Once you do that you can dump `std` and `mean`.

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import numpy
import ruamel.yaml

path = Path('numpy.yaml')

np = numpy
data = dict(
  std = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]),
  mean = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0]),
)

def represent_numpy_float64(self, value):
    return self.represent_float(value)  # alternatively dump as a tagged float

def represent_numpy_int64(self, value):
    return self.represent_int(value)  # alternatively dump as a tagged int

def represent_numpy_array(self, array, flow_style=None):
    tag = '!numpy.ndarray'
    value = []
    node = ruamel.yaml.nodes.SequenceNode(tag, value, flow_style=flow_style)
    for elem in array:
        node_elem = self.represent_data(elem)
        value.append(node_elem)
    if flow_style is None:
        node.flow_style = True
    return node


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Representer.add_representer(numpy.ndarray, represent_numpy_array)
yaml.Representer.add_representer(numpy.float64, represent_numpy_float64)
yaml.Representer.add_representer(numpy.int64, represent_numpy_int64)
yaml.dump(data, path)
print(path.read_text(), end='')  # the file ends in a newline, don't add another one
```

which gives:

```
std: !numpy.ndarray [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
mean: !numpy.ndarray [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

`ruamel.yaml`'s default round-trip loader, can load the resuling file:

```py
import sys

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
rtd = yaml.load(path)
print(f'{rtd}')
print('type of std', type(rtd['std']))
yaml.dump(rtd, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
{'std': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 'mean': [0, 0, 0, 0]}
type of std <class 'ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq'>
std: !numpy.ndarray [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
mean: !numpy.ndarray [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

as you can see, this doesn't load the file as a `numpy.ndarray`. For that you need to provide a constructor,
for the tag (since we don't dump the floats/ints tagged, you don't need to provide a constructor for those):

```py
def construct_numpy_array(self, node):
    return numpy.array(self.construct_sequence(node))

yaml.Constructor.add_constructor('!numpy.ndarray', construct_numpy_array)

rtd = yaml.load(path)
print(f'{rtd}')
print('type of std', type(rtd['std']))
```

which gives:

```
{'std': array([1., 1., 1., 1.]), 'mean': array([0, 0, 0, 0])}
type of std <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Note that the above doesn't work for (indirectly) recursive dumps, as the `construct_numpy_array`
does not have a `yield` statement. It would be better to do something like:

```
def construct_numpy_array(self, node):
    data = numpy.array([])
    yield data
    numpy.append(data, numpy.array(self.construct_sequence(node)))
```

but that did not give the same result (because of my unfamiliarity with numpy).

Comment: I've seen that, I'm working on it ! If I find a solution, I will post it here :)

Comment: I added some code that should get you most of the way

Comment: Thanks for providing some code @Anthon
I have worked on it yesterday and found a way to represent it by converting the values to Python List. I've tried your solution, and it's working well as well ! Thanks :)